# Writing POSCAR for monolayer and mulitiple layers for 2D materials

Tags: vasp

I am learning how to write POSCAR for monolayer and multiple layers of 2D materials like Bi2Se3, could you please provide some useful hints how to write POSCAR quickly especially for multiple layers, for instance, 3 layers?

Answer (score 4):

If you're starting out from bulk structures (which can be obtained from databases like [Materials Project](https://materialsproject.org/)), I've found [Pymatgen](https://pymatgen.org/index.html)'s [SlabGenerator](https://pymatgen.org/pymatgen.core.surface.html#pymatgen.core.surface.SlabGenerator) to be useful. Its class definition looks like this.
`SlabGenerator(initial_structure, miller_index, min_slab_size, min_vacuum_size, lll_reduce=False, center_slab=False, in_unit_planes=False, primitive=True, max_normal_search=None, reorient_lattice=True)`

You can choose which plane to cut (`miller_index`), how many layers you want to include (`min_slab_size`), etc, which should simplify the generation of monolayer or multi-layer `POSCAR`s from bulk inputs.

If you start with monolayer structures (for example, you could get the `POSCAR`s from [2DMatPedia](http://www.2dmatpedia.org/)), I'm not sure if there's any out-of-the-box method to generate `POSCAR`s for multi-layered structures directly, but you can use Pymatgen's [Structure](https://pymatgen.org/pymatgen.core.structure.html#pymatgen.core.structure.Structure) class and other utilities to get the job done rather conveniently.